# Detect navigation change in SPFX Application customizer

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have a SPFX customizer that displays a banner in the `topPlaceholder`. When the page loads, if it's a list, then it performs a calculation and then displays the banner.

When I move from one library to another, because the page isn't performing a full load, I found out I need use the `navigatedEvent`. This fires when the navigation changes.

However, I need to display the banner differently depending on what folder I'm in within a single document library. When navigating from one folder to another in a document library the navigatedEvent doesn't seem to fire, even though I am navigating to a different location.

Is this a bug with the `navigatedEvent`, or should I be using a different event?

```
    public onInit(): Promise<void> {
       var rootSiteFullUrl = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;
    pnp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });

   this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this,  this.renderControl);  
    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }


    private renderControl(){
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Available placeholders: ${this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames.map(name => PlaceholderName[name]).join(', ')}`);


    //handling the top placeholder
    if(!this._topPlaceholder){
      this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
          PlaceholderName.Top, 
          {onDispose: this._onDispose});

      if(!this._topPlaceholder){
        console.error(`The expected placholder (Top) was not found.`);
        return;
      }  
    }

    if(this._topPlaceholder.domElement){
        const element : React.ReactElement<IInfoBarMainProps> = React.createElement(
          MainClosureBar,{
            siteRelativeUrl: this._siteRelativeURL,
            listID: this._listID,
            rootSiteUrl: this._rootSiteURL,
            context: this.context
          }
        );

        ReactDom.render(element, this._topPlaceholder.domElement);
    }
  }

  private _onDispose(){
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `[IInfoBarApplicationCustomizer._onDispose] Disposed custom top placeholders`);
  }
```

I have a feeling that there isn't an event for navigating inside a folder, as when I'm in a folder, there is nothing within the `this.context.pageContext` that indicates that I'm in a folder.

Comment: This could be indeed very well a limitation in SPFx. The best would be to submit an issue in GitHub at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues to have the SharePoint engineers confirm/deny this.

Comment: Thanks @WaldekMastykarz-MVP I will raise an issue in GitHub later today. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone following the links https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1254

Answer (score 0):

TWO OPTIONS TO FACE THIS ISSUE:

**OPTION 1:**

Track down the url changes during conditional page load ( no full page load ) following [the guide from microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data).

**OPTION 2:**

Use the mutation observer and monitor the breadcrumb. Here is some code that will help you to reach your goal:

```
    let targetNode1 = document.querySelector(".od-ItemsScopeItemContent > div > div > div > div >div");

    this._observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => this._myCustomHeaderBasedOnCurrentFolder(mutation));
    });

    if (targetNode1) {
      this._observer.observe(targetNode1, {
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        subtree:true,
      });
    }
  }
```

The method

> _myCustomHeaderBasedOnCurrentFolder

Is the action you want to perform when browsing through the folders. You will need to tune up a bit the observer config for a better monitoring.