# When navigating from one folder to another, the navigatedEvent doesn't fire in SPFx Extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have some logic based on which folder User is in. But it fails as when I navigates between the folder the **navigatedEvent** is not firing.

Go to Root Folder add some console and then navigate to any sub folder and write the query string in console so you can check whether the event fired or not.

How can I trace the navigation between the folders in SPFx Extension.

**EDIT 1**

**I checked this with two different tenants and in both the tenants I am facing this issue.**

Here is the code snippet.

```
@override
 public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);

     return Promise.resolve<void>();
 }
  private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {

  let queryParms = new UrlQueryParameterCollection(window.location.href);
   let myParm : string = decodeURIComponent(queryParms.getValue("id"));
   console.log("QUery String: " + myParm);

   console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
   console.log(
     "Available placeholders: ",
     this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
       .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
       .join(", ")
   );

   // Handling the top placeholder
    {
     const topPlaceholder  = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
       PlaceholderName.Top,
       { onDispose: this._onDispose }
     );

     // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
     if (!topPlaceholder) {
       console.error("The expected placeholder (Top) was not found.");
       return;
     }

     if (this.properties) {
       let topString: string = this.properties.Top;
       if (!topString) {
         topString = "(Top property was not defined.)";
       }

       if (topPlaceholder.domElement) {
         topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
         <div class="${styles.app}">
           <div class="${styles.top}">
             <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info" aria-hidden="true"></i> ${escape(
               topString
             )}
           </div>
         </div>`;
       }
     }
   }

   // Handling the bottom placeholder
 {
   const bottomPlaceholder  = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
       PlaceholderName.Bottom,
       { onDispose: this._onDispose }
     );

     // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
     if (!bottomPlaceholder) {
       console.error("The expected placeholder (Bottom) was not found.");
       return;
     }

     if (this.properties) {
       let bottomString: string = this.properties.Bottom;
       if (!bottomString) {
         bottomString = "(Bottom property was not defined.)";
       }

       if (bottomPlaceholder.domElement) {
         bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
         <div class="${styles.app}">
           <div class="${styles.bottom}">
             <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info" aria-hidden="true"></i> ${escape(
               bottomString
             )}
           </div>
         </div>`;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I already checked [This link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233889/detect-navigation-change-in-spfx-application-customizer) and also reviewed similar posts on GitHub ([#1254](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1254), [#1042](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1042))
 which states the issue if fixed but in my case it is not.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no way to track the discussed navigation event.

The only effective solution is to track down the url changes during conditional page load ( no full page load ) following [the guide from microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data).

On the other hand, I have created this small s[pfx extension that tracks the url changes on conditional page load or sharepoint page transition](https://github.com/holylander/spfx-public-apps/tree/master/spfx-nav.tracker), which uses the previous approach and exposes such info as a dynamic data source, maybe it could be helpful for someone else.